# Постановка запятой.

Tags: пунктуация

**-Вы что, обезумели?**

Как можно объяснить постановку запятой в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Без запятой можно использовать, но будет другой вариант. (Типа Вы что (наречие) обезумели? ну-ка давайте приходите в себя - не до этого сейчас).Тут предполагается продолжение речи.. А в Вашем варианте просто негодование и дальше нет слов. И запятая, делая паузу после междометия (а именно им является данное ЧТО), усиливает значение и акцент слова ОБЕЗУМЕЛИ.

Answer (score 0):

В порядке имхи: "что" здесь в роли сказуемого, таким образом имеем два донородных члена, подлежащих разделению запятой.
Других вариантов грамматического разбора как-то в голову не приходит.